# MSCGen for Mac OS X

Tags: uml, tool-uml

I am starting a new SW project between client and server and would like to utilize some SW tools for constructing the message flow.

Is there any one has MSCGen that is built for Mac OS X ?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814/best-uml-application-for-mac-osx-cross-platform

Answer (score 7):

In order of preference, I suggest:

Install using Homebrew (assumes you have previously [installed Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)):

```
brew install mscgen
```

Another way is to use Macports, but Macports still uses version 0.18:

```
sudo port install mscgen
```

And finally, I compiled mscgen 0.2 on Mac OS/X 10.7.3 just now:

```
wget http://www.mcternan.me.uk/mscgen/software/mscgen-src-0.20.tar.gz
tar xvfz mscgen-src-0.20.tar.gz 
cd mscgen-0.20/
./configure
make
make check
sudo make install # conflicts with Homebrew
```

Comment: I had to run `brew install Caskroom/cask/xquartz` followed by `brew install homebrew/x11/mscgen` to install with Homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

[websequencediagrams.com](http://www.websequencediagrams.com/) ?